# How to convert Excel text data in to string in Matlab

Tags: string, excel, matlab

I want to read a specific character from a cell of Excel file in Matlab. I did the following:
[num2,A] = xlsread( xlsfile, 2 );

where A = 'r 1.0'

but the format of A does not match with "string" type, so I can not use the string functions of Maltab to continue my work.

So, is it a possible way to convert what I read from a cell of excel into string type in Matlab?

Thanks a lot,
BehZad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is a cell array of strings, thus you need to access its content with `{ }`:

```
B = A{1}
whos B
```